# Google map drow route between current location and point

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to draw a route between the current location and another point. I wrote code which can check the current location and also put the point on the map on a map click.  At the moment, the program is working perfectly, 
but I want to draw another route between the current location and a new point( point witch I added map on Map click listener).
My code is below, does anyone know how I can to add this logic on my code?

```
public class GPS extends Activity implements

    OnMyLocationChangeListener,OnMapClickListener,
    OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerDragListener {

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;
Circle myCircle;
Location myLocation;
TextView tvLocInfo, GPSLocation;
LatLng latLng;
boolean markerClicked;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
Polygon polygon;

public Button btnline;
double Clicklatitude, Clicklongitude, latitude, longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);
    markerPoints=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    btnline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tvLocInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GpsTxt);
    GPSLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GPSLocation);
    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.GpsMap);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    myMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    myMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);




    markerClicked = false;
    btnline.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}





@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    // Getting longitude of the current location
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    // Zoom in the Google Map

    GPSLocation.setText(latitude + " " + longitude);
    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    LatLng locLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());
    double accuracy = location.getAccuracy();

    if (myCircle == null) {
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(locLatLng)
                // set center
                .radius(accuracy)
                // set radius in meters
                .fillColor(Color.RED).strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
                .strokeWidth(5);

        myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    } else {
        myCircle.setCenter(locLatLng);
        myCircle.setRadius(accuracy);
    }
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    // myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locLatLng));

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {


}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    Clicklatitude = point.latitude;
    Clicklongitude = point.longitude;
    tvLocInfo.setText(Clicklatitude + " " + Clicklongitude);
    if (point != null)
        myMap.clear();
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).draggable(true));

    markerClicked = false;

}
```

}

I want to get a like this result [enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/839w1o7zh/)

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved same thing via this code. This will be some different Code from what you have tried.

First of all Implement your class with this two things 
          `implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener`

When you implement OnMapReadyCallback you will get pre-define method called 
"OnMapReady"

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    destiLati =  40.728634;
    destiLong = -73.974956;
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

    // Add a marker in Destination/Desire point and move the camera
    DestinationPoint = new LatLng(destiLati, destiLong);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DestinationPoint).title("Destination 
   Point")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location)));
    //To move camera to Desination Location.
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(DestinationPoint, 10));


    //Permission To get Current Location
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

To get current location I have made one method and when you implement LocationListener 
it will give you pre-define method called  "onLocationChanged"

```
 private void getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
    }
    catch(SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   //This thing will get User's current location
    originLati = location.getLatitude();
    originLong = location.getLongitude();
    exeTask();
    //Log.d(originLati.toString(),"This is the value of orginalati" + originLati.toString() + " " + originLong.toString());

}
```

To get path between Your current location and destination..
you need to pass data to google API it will write one JSON result 
you have to get this result and show it into Polyline(to display path)

```
 private void exeTask(){

    String originPl = "origin=" + originLati.toString() + "," + originLong.toString();
    String destipl = "destination=" + destiLati.toString() + "," + destiLong.toString();
    String sensor = "sensor-false";
    String mode = "mode-driving";
    String param = originPl + "&" + destipl + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode + "&key='Your_API_KEY'";
     final_url  = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" + param;
    //Log.d(final_url,"This is the URL which was created");
    TaskRequestDirections taskRequestDirections = new TaskRequestDirections();
    taskRequestDirections.execute(final_url);

}


private String requestDirection(String reqUrl) throws IOException {
    String responseString = "";
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        //TO get the in String format response result
        inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }

        responseString = stringBuffer.toString();
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStreamReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return responseString;
}

public class TaskRequestDirections extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String responseString = "";
        try {
            responseString = requestDirection(strings[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //Parse json/ Data will come from here..
        TaskParser taskParser = new TaskParser();
        taskParser.execute(s);
    }
}

public class TaskParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> > {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(strings[0]);
            DirectionsParser directionsParser = new DirectionsParser();
            routes = directionsParser.parse(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> lists) {
        //To get list route and display it into the map

        ArrayList points = null;

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = null;

        for (List<HashMap<String, String>> path : lists) {
            points = new ArrayList();
            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            for (HashMap<String, String> point : path) {
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lon"));

                points.add(new LatLng(lat,lon));
            }

            polylineOptions.addAll(points);
            polylineOptions.width(10);
            polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            polylineOptions.geodesic(true);
        }

        if (polylineOptions!=null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Direction not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

And finally call this pre-define Class as it show here to decode polylines and get json array result

```
  public class DirectionsParser {
/**
 * Returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude from a JSONObject
 */
public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        // Loop for all routes
        for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
            jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //Loop for all legs
            for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                //Loop for all steps
                for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List list = decodePolyline(polyline);

                    //Loop for all points
                    for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                        hm.put("lon", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return routes;
}

/**
 * Method to decode polyline
 * Source : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 */
private List decodePolyline(String encoded) {

    List poly = new ArrayList();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
 }
```

Hope This help :)